# How to insert a field from Excel Sheet to Access Database with a WHERE condition

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

I've been wracking my mind over this problem for a while and I was wondering if there is a solution!

So I have a table called R1 with two Column: [Department] and [DepartmentQV] in Access, the [Department] Column has a few fields with values but the [DepartmentQV] column is blank

I also have a spreadsheet in Excel that also has a [Department] column and a [DepartmentQV] column. The [Department] Column is identical to the one in Access but the [DepartmentQV] column has values.

All I want to do is use ADODB and SQL to pull in the [DepartmentQV] values from the Excel sheet into the Access database where the [Department] values match.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all, I keep getting the same error "No Value Given for One or More Required Parameters" and I am completely puzzled. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Best,
Kurt

Here is my code so far!

```
 lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  dbPath = glob_sdbPath
  dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  dbWs = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
  scn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
  dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$B2:C" & lastRow & "]"
  cn.Open scn

  sSql = "INSERT INTO  R1([Department_QV])"
  sSql = sSql & " SELECT [Spoilage] FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh & "    WHERE " & dsh  & ".[Department] = R1.[Department]"

  cn.Execute sSql
```

Comment: In your range B2:Cx, are you omitting the header row?  In that case, the recordset won't have the  names you expect.  Also, your SQL is weird: are you trying to INSERT new rows or UPDATE existing ones?

Comment: The header row is actually in B2:C2 and I am actually trying to update existing rows. I've always had trouble using update with adodb and access, you wouldn't happen to know a way I could implement what I am looking to do with update would you? Still no luck so far sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is getting the update to occur between Access and Excel using ADO.  When I tried to INNER JOIN the derived Excel table against the Access table and perform the update, I received the error:

```
"Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
You cannot edit this field because it resides in a linked Excel spreadsheet. The ability to edit data in a linked Excel spreadsheet has been disabled in this Access Release."
```

Nevermind the Access table is not linked to Excel, I couldn't find a solution to this out there.  I decided instead to push the Excel data into a temp table in Access and run the update against the R1 and the temp table.  Another way to perform the updates would have been to open two recordsets, one the Excel table, the other the Access table, and search one against the other and update, but I opted against it.

(I referenced both Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library as well as Microsoft ADOX Ext. 2.8 for DDL And Security so I would have intellisense.  You can instantiate the objects however you like.):

```
Public Sub ExcelToAcessUpdate()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rstTables As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog

    Dim dbWb As String
    Dim dbWs As String
    Dim dsh As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Dim dbPath As String
    Dim scn As String
    Dim sTempTable As String
    Dim sSql As String

    dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    dbWs = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
    dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$B2:C" & lastRow & "]"
    lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    dbPath = glob_sdbPath
    scn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

    'This is the name of the temp table in Access
    'we will use to hold our Excel data.
    sTempTable = "tblMyExcelTemp"

    cn.Open scn

    'Make the ADO connection get a recordset of tables in database.
    Set rstTables = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)

    'If temp table we want to use already exists in db, delete it.
    With rstTables
        Do Until .EOF
            If .Fields("TABLE_TYPE") = "TABLE" And _
               .Fields("TABLE_NAME") = sTempTable Then
                    Set cat.ActiveConnection = cn
                    cat.Tables.Delete sTempTable

                    Exit Do
            End If

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    'Get all our Excel data and push it into temp table.
    sSql = "SELECT [Department], [Spoilage] INTO " & sTempTable & " " & _
           "FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh

    cn.Execute sSql

    'Update R1 using inner join against Excel Temp table.
    sSql = "UPDATE R1 INNER JOIN " & sTempTable & " e ON R1.[Department] = e.[Department] " & _
           " SET Department_QV = e.[Spoilage]"

    cn.Execute sSql

ExitMe:
    If cn Is Nothing = False Then
        If cn.State <> adStateClosed Then
            cn.Close
        End If
    End If

    Set cat = Nothing
    Set rstTables = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    'Lazy error handling, need to go through cn.Errors collection, actually.
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    GoTo ExitMe

End Sub
```

I'm not a huge fan of temp table solutions, but it works, and can be a paradigm for you if you need to do this kind of thing a lot.  Hopefully it will work for you.  A cursor-based solution using recordsets would have been too inefficient, but I guess it could be done that way as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough alternative! I even learned a few more neat tricks with adodb through your method as well!

Comment: @bluecat: Very welcome.  Hope it helps you out or sets you on a better path, at least.